# D3.js zoomTo point in a 2D map (projection)

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I've some issue with D3 zooming.

I've built a map with D3 and topoJSON stuff, and when I search a city, a point appear on the map.

I used this code to have a constrained zoom on my map:
http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4987520

It's work fine with all my stuff, now I try to improve the experience by adding a zoom to the point after my search.

I've seen some interessant code here for that: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/6242308

But on two links there is two different zoom functions and I don't know how to mix. I've no error on my code, but the zoom go always at the same point (center of the map I think), even if my point return different locations in console log.... Don't understand why

Here is some samples of codes:

```
var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
    .scaleExtent([1, 30])
    .on("zoom", move);

 var path = d3.geo.path()
    .projection(projection);

 var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")")
    .call(zoom);

 var g = svg.append("g");

//This is called when ajax research
function setPlaces(jsonData){
    ... code stuff
    var point = [authors[0].birth_place.lon, authors[0].birth_place.lat];
    svg.transition().call(zoomTo(point, 4).event);
}

function zoomTo(location, scale) {
    var point = projection(location);
    return zoom
       .translate([width / 2 - point[0] * scale, height / 2 - point[1] * scale])
       .scale(scale);
}

function move() {
var t = d3.event.translate,
        s = d3.event.scale;
t[0] = Math.min(width / 2 * (s - 1), Math.max(width / 2 * (1 - s), t[0]));
t[1] = Math.min(height / 2 * (s - 1) + 230 * s, Math.max(height / 2 * (1 - s) - 230 * s, t[1]));
zoom.translate(t);
g.style("stroke-width", 1 / s).attr("transform", "translate(" + t + ")scale(" + s + ")");
}
```

Comment: Have you seen [this example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/2206590)?

Comment: Yes but was not useful :/ The second link I've posted is what I want but I've already an another zoom type (pan + zoom) on my map and I try to mix both but no success

Comment: edited the post, now I get a zoom but always on the same point (center of the map) wtf ?

Comment: In the `clicked` function in the example, look at the last block of code. `k` is your scale factor and `x` and `y` the projected coordinates of the point you want to zoom in on.

Comment: It's already what I have look at the zoomTo on my code, same thing.

Comment: Could you post a complete working example please, preferably somewhere like jsfiddle?

Comment: I've tried, but I can't setup D3 in jsfiddle. I paste this code http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4987520 here: http://jsfiddle.net/7zH25/ nothing appear, can you help me to setup the fiddle please ? Thx u

Comment: I really need to see the code that you've been working on, not the example code.

Comment: Yes but I need to set up D3 in jsfiddle before adding my code. I can't put all the code directly coz there is a lot of ajax call + API Rest with SF2 in local. I want to built you a simple version of what is not working

Comment: You may find something else like [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/) easier as it allows you to upload files.

Comment: Seems a bit crap, the preview doesn't work in chrome, even if i Download the file. But it's work in firefox for me.

http://plnkr.co/edit/BO95jH6Xhmo623rGqcHF?p=preview
Press key up and you'll see the zoom don't go in the right place (I've draw a red point in France)

Comment: It doesn't work for me, but it looks like you're setting translate and scale only on the zoom behaviour. You need to set that on the SVG.

Comment: The result is the same in the svg, in the Zoom function I've delete the return and put this code: g.transition()
      .duration(750)
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")scale(" + scale + ")translate(" + -point[0] + "," + -point[1] + ")")
      .style("stroke-width", 1.5 / scale + "px");

Same thing :/

Comment: Ok, must be something somewhere else that's messing it up. Could you send me a complete example by email so I can have a look at it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main issue in your code was that longitude and latitude were switched in the call that zoomed to the point. Apart from this, the zoom worked fine. However, as you're using the zoom behaviour for the map, setting it through this is better than directly through the SVG transform. The relevant code is below.

```
function zoomTo(location, scale) {
  var point = projection(location);

  zoom.scale(scale);
  zoom.translate([-point[0] * scale, -point[1] * scale]);

  return zoom;
}
```